# Cómo recibir un SYS_REFCURSOR de una base de datos ORACLE a NODE JS

Tags: nodejs, oracle, plsql

Desde NodeJS hago una llamada a un procedimiento dentro de una base de datos Oracle que devuelve un sys_refcursor, pero en Node llega como undefined.

El código en Oracle es el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_unidad
IS
    unidad_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN unidad_cursor FOR SELECT uni_tipo FROM UNIDAD;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(unidad_cursor);
END;
```

El código en Node es el siguiente:

```
const getFromDatabase = async function(sql, binds, autoCommit){
    const conexion = await oracledb.getConnection(database);
    const resultado = await conexion.execute(sql, binds, {autoCommit});
    conexion.release();
    return resultado;
}

-----

router.get('/test', async (req, res)=>{
    const sql = 'BEGIN get_unidad(); END;';
    const result  = await getFromDatabase(sql, [], false);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Cómo se hace para enviar un sys_refcursor desde oracle y que Node sea capaz de leerlo?

Comment: Qué tienes en la variable binds? Ahí deberías poner variables tipo oracledb.CURSOR

Comment: @Alfabravo no sé qué es una variable tipo oracledb.CURSOR. Estoy iniciando un proyecto con NodeJS y Oracle, y necesito recibir cursores llamando a procedimientos desde node, no sé de qué me hablas cuando te refieres a la variable binds. Se que en un lugar de mi código puse un parámetro llamado bind, pero ni idea de qué es eso

Comment: Usa el refcursor como parámetro out del SP y ese binds contiene todas las variables que usas para enviar o recibir variables binding (como haciendo un prepared statement).

Comment: @Alfabravo no entiendo, podrías mostrármelo en código, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asigna el resultado de la función a una variable de retorno parametrizada y maneja el cursor:

```
const resultado = await conexion.execute( 'BEGIN :cursor := get_unidad(); END;' 
                                        , { cursor: { type: oracledb.CURSOR
                                                    , dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                                                    } 
                                          }
                                        );
const cursor = resultado.outBinds.cursor;
const filas = await cursor.getRows();
```